# Select only the child of an element, identified by his class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I activate the click event only on the child of the element (identify by his class) that I clicked?

I try this but seems that active all the onclick event of the `.a-collaps-button` on the page (I have multiple `.collaps-button` and multiple `.a-collaps-button`)

```
<button class="collaps-button">
  <a href="#adminModal" class="a-collaps-button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showModalContentjs('modificy')">Modificy</a>
</button>
```

```js
$('.collaps-button').click(function () {
  $(this).children('.a-collaps-button').click();
});
```

For the CSS I do this and it works

```
$(function () {
  $('.collaps-button').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.a-collaps-button').css('color', '#f44242');
    $(this).children('.a-collaps-button').css('text-decoration', 'none');
  }, function () {
    $(this).children('.a-collaps-button').css('color', 'white');
    $(this).children('.a-collaps-button').css('text-decoration', 'none');
  });
});
```

Comment: why use js to style a hover css?  Also I don't think an anchor inside a button is valid

Comment: @Pete I'm going to reopen this as, while that duplicate matches the OPs question, there's a massive flaw in their HTML which renders the point of the question moot.

Answer (score 1):

Your major issue is that your HTML is invalid. You cannot nest clickable elements, ie. you cannot place an `a` element inside a `button`.

To fix this, remove the `a` element and simply attach whatever logic you execute on click of that `a` to the click event of the `button` instead. Also note that you should not be using outdated `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive event handlers, such as `addEventListener()` or jQuery's `on()` or event shortcut methods, such as `click()`.

Also note that you shouldn't use JS to amend the UI. Your `hover` logic is much more suited to CSS. Try this:

```js
$('.collaps-button').click(function() {
  showModalContentjs('modificy');
});

function showModalContentjs(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

```css
.collaps-button {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}
.collaps-button:hover {
  color: #f44242;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="collaps-button">Modificy</button>
```

Comment: I use the <a> element because i use ajax and for not reload the page after every onclick event. So i use <a> in a <button> for mantain the button style that i had already created in other page where i don't use ajax

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that. You will have to use one or the other. Whichever you choose, the logic above remains the same. You can very easily use CSS to make an `a` element appear like a button, and vice versa, though